# 繰り返し構文内でのDataFrameの構築について

Tags: python, pandas

ある機械学習のfitをデータの範囲を少しづつ変えて、
逐次行い（for文で実施）その予測結果を出力する際の話なんですが、
繰り返しによる予測結果全体をひとつのDataFrameに蓄積して出力するには
どのように書けばよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dictionaryを作って最後にdataframeにするのが良いと思います

```
r = ['range_1', 'range_2', 'range_3']  # 範囲のリストをつくる
l = list()

for rng in r:
    # 範囲を切り出す
    # fit する
    # 結果を出す (=>acc)
    l.append(acc)

d = {'range': r, 'result': l}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```